# problematic proof of the moving lemma, second part ? 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, chow-groups

I have heard several times that the proof of the second part of the Chow's moving lemma (of algebraic geometry), is problematic; and that this is the reason Fulton, Intersection theory, 
does not use it to define intersection product.

Has anyone heard similar claims, and if so, what/where is the gap ?

For completeness, I mean the moving lemma, say as stated in 
J.Roberts, Appendix 2(Algebraic Geometry, 1970, ed. Oort). 
The problem claimed is with the 'Moreover' part.

Lemma (Chow's moving lemma). - Let $W$ and $W'$ be cycles on X. Then
there exists a cycle $W''$ rationally equivalent to $W'$ such that $W \cdot W''$ 
is defined. Moreover, there exists an algebraic family 
$\{Z(t)\}_{t \in P^1(k)}$ deforming 
$W'$ into $W$ such that $Z(t)\cdot W$ is defined for almost all t.

Comment: This is not the reason that the moving lemma is not used in Fulton's book. The way intersection theory is developed there is more general, since it requires no quasi-projectivity assumptions, and much more powerful, since he constructs a "refined" intersection product which is impossible using the moving lemma.

Comment: I think that the proof of Roberts is correct for the case where the ground field is algebraic closed. May be the gap, if any, happens when k is not algebraic closed. By the way, in the second part, the family Z(t) is rational ($t\in \mathbb{P}^1(k)$), which is stronger than that you stated.  

Comment: Nono, thanks, I corrected the statement. I should have been more clear: the claim I heard was that there is no complete proof in the literature, or rather that some experts think so. 

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. However, I still do not know what parts of the proof that you think are problematic. Did the experts you contacted say so? Do you consider X not be smooth, or do you consider the case where the field k is not algebraic closed, or else? There is also the paper "Moving algebraic cycles of bounded degree" on Inventiones math. by Friedlander and Lawson, in which they present a proof of the result in Roberts as well (see page 99 on in the paper).  

Comment: Nono, thanks. I do not really know, I've only heard these claims 
but was unable to clarify what is meant...I think that at some point someone convinced Suslin that there is a problem with published proofs, but I do not know in what generality etc, and that was few years back (but after the paper you refer to).  

Comment: If the story goes as you said, then there must be some problem. But since you don't know what problem is, it is hard to say. Anyway, I still think that the case when X is smooth and k is algebraic closed, there is no problem. There is a book of Eisenbud and Harris, which dates 27 April 2010 http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic720403.files/book.pdf which discusses Chow moving lemma in Chapter 2 for X smooth quasi-projective and k algebraic closed. I guess the date should be later than the story you referred to, so there would not be any problem in this case.     

Comment: By the way, the first part says that you can find a cycle W" which is rationally equivalent to W' such that W.W" is well-defined. If you accept the first part, then I think you must accept the second part as well, at least in principle. This is because to say that W" is rationally equivalent to W', you must have a family W(t) with $t\in \mathbb{P}^1(k)$ so that $W(0)=W'$ and $W(\infty )=W"$. Now this family intersects properly with $W$ at one point $\infty$, it should do so for a dense open set in $\mathbb{P}^1$. 

Comment: There is another problem with using the moving lemma to *define* intersection products, and that is well-definedness. That is to say, if $\alpha, \beta$ are given, and $\alpha'$ and $\alpha''$ are rationally equivalent to $\alpha$ and meet $\beta$ properly, then one should check that $\alpha' \cdot \beta = \alpha''\cdot \beta$. Moreover, one wants the intersection product to factor through rational equivalence, so one should vary $\beta$ as well. This method is used in the Stacks Project, and all details are carefully carried out there.